# Apostrophe in form, php and mySQL

Tags: php, apostrophe

This is so weird, i'm working on a new server (not my own), and I have a strange behavior I never saw.

I have a simple form with one field in it and a submit button.

On the server I have a simple php file to receive the post.

I try to add a slash in front of the apostrophe, but it's not working at all and it does bad thing too...

This is what I enter in the field

`Bill's`

in the php I have this

```
echo mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']); // === Bill's

echo addslashes($_POST['name']); // === Bill's

echo addslashes("Bill's");  // === Bill\'s
```

Also the bad thing is if I add this fields to mysql I got this `Bill&#039s`

I do the same on my regular sever and it work great?

Before I call my customer and said he have a bad setting somwhere.

Can someone tell me how it is possible

A big thanks

Comment: **WARNING** You're using a deprecated database API. It's advised to use a more [up to date database api](http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

Comment: Are you doing any manipulation on `$_POST` before you reach `mysql_real_escape_string`? It looks like you may be using [**`htmlspecialchars`**](http://uk1.php.net/htmlspecialchars). This would cause no escape on the `'` when using `$_POST`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, no I do nothing on the post and I understand  I need to use mysqli, but why the addslashes doesn't work on the $_POST variable, I'm speechless...

Comment: Finally I found no answer, I'm pretty sure it was something on the server, a security gadget or something like that. All the POST and GET variable are htmlentities not only the apostrophe but all html code like < or > are transform... In my book this is a bad gadget :O) Thanks to all

Comment: Oh wow. Is it on any type of framework, or pre-built script?

Comment: Still don't know.... For this one I tell the customer if he want me to do the project he need to change his hosting, and he did :O) Thanks